# How to write a variable that is in requeset in Golang GRPC

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have a quick question. Is there any chance to save in some way variable from request.
This is my protoc file where i can generate code for client and server.

```
service RecTask {
  rpc AllPath(UserToken) returns (UserToken) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      get: "/*"
    };
  }
  rpc Auth(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (TokenRender) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      get: "/auth"
    };
  }
  rpc StartTracking(UserToken) returns (UserToken) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      get: "/auth/{user_token}"
    };
  }
}

message UserToken {
  string user_token = 1;
  int32 user_counter = 2;
}
```

I just want to count user request after "auth"

below two functions: First one initialize counter to 0 another trying to update from request:

```
func (s *RecTask) StartTracking(ctx context.Context, req *pb.UserToken) (*pb.UserToken, error) {
    if contains(tokens, req.UserToken) {
        response := &pb.UserToken{
            UserCounter: 0,
        }
        return response, nil

func (s *RecTask) AllPath(ctx context.Context, req *pb.UserToken) (res *pb.UserToken, err error) {
    response := &pb.UserToken{
        UserCounter: +1,
    }
```

If anyone can tell me how I could store the current counter of a user in a variable, for example "counter", I would be very grateful, Best

Answer (score 0):

One option is that put the user counter variable in the custom `RecTask`

```golang
type RecTask struct {
   userCounter map[string]int32
}

func (r *RecTask) Auth (ctx context.Context, req *pb.UserToken) (res *pb.UserToken, err error) {
    // handle auth logic

    // increase user count by token
    if _, ok := r.userCounter[req.Token]; ok {
        r.userCounter[req.Token]++
    } else {
        r.userCounter[req.Token] = 1
    }
}
```